# Ruby: grammar name for :variable

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm learning rails by working with some examples. Here is my sample model file:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable
end
```

The ruby grammar I don't know is:

```
 devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
             :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable
```

After some researchs, I know above command uses poetry mode of ruby, it means method calling without parentheses. so above command should be:

```
devise(:database_authenticatable, :registerable,
             :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable)
```

I still don't understand what is grammar name of `:variable`. I have searched but only know `@variable` for instance, `@@variable` for class ...

Thanks

Comment: These are [symbols](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Symbol.html), basically immutable (i.e. unchangeable) strings. They are generally used to refer to things in Ruby by name, e.g. method names, options, ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not strictly certain that this is what you are looking for, but any string of characters preceded by a `:` is a [Symbol](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/Symbol.html).

To summarize, a symbol is like a string, except each mention of the same symbol literal is a reference to the same immutable underlying value. In this case, each of those symbols (`:database_authenticable`, `:registerable`, etc...) are giving specific values as arguments to the function `devise`, presumably setting certain attributes of it.

Answer (score 1):

Any word that is preceded by a `:` is called a [symbol](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/Symbol.html). As @Holger mentioned in his comment, a symbol is (at its simplest form) an immutable string.

Symbols are most commonly used as keys and to reference keys within a [Hash](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Hash.html):

```
hash = { key: "value" }
```

`"value"` can then be referenced by calling the hash's key as a symbol:

```
hash[:key]
=> "value"
```

Answer (score 1):

These are called symbols. 
more here

> http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Symbol.html